# Setting z-index of layer when using setNotificationNode in Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, notifications, layer, scene

Since I'm having performance issues with using a UIView parallaxing images in the background of a transparent Cocos2D scene (it was fine in iOS 6), I think I may use the notification node to run the parallax since I need the parallax running between scene transitions.  I've tested setting the notifications node, but I haven't figured out how to make it display in a different z-order. I want it to display under everything in the scene.

Right now for my test I have

```
CCLayer *layer = [CCLayer node];
CCLabelTTF *labelTest = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"test" fntFile:@"readySetGo.fnt"];
labelTest.position = CGPointMake(100,100);
[layer addChild:labelTest];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNotificationNode:layer]; // Layer should be placed here

[layer onEnter]; // Schedule for updates
```

Comment: The notification node is designed to be on top of all other nodes. If you want to change that you'll probably have to change the source code, look into CCDirector how (in what order) that node gets drawn.

Comment: Thanks. The strange thing is that I can't even get any results when I search for the method "setNotificationNode"

Comment: that's because it's a property, try searching for just "notificationnode"

Comment: Thanks =) All I had to do is swap the order of [runningScene_ visit]; and [notificationNode_visit]; in CCDirectorIOS.m